# Is it possible to handle multiple form updates in single php page?

Tags: php

I have multiple forms with different fields in them.

I want all these forms' to use a single update/edit script, is this possible.

I haven't tried yet with the code. If it's possible can anyone please provide the reference like or method to carry out that way?

Comment: Why not make it a single form then? Inputs can have an attribute `form` that links them to a form, even if the inputs themselves are all over the page.

Comment: you mean 2 forms with 2 submit buttons ? If so, only one form can be submitted at any point of time. Tell your use case why you want to do so ?

Comment: I am not I understand everything in here, but to use a form within the same page you can use <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> but for the multiple form, sorry but I don't understand the question, you should try something and then post it in here so we can all understand

Answer (score 3):

Name the submit buttons uniquely in each of your pages that the user interacts with and then use the name="..." property to decide which form sent the data.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
//do your code for form 1
}

if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
//do your code for form 2
}
```

`submit1` and `submit2` are submit button names